# How to remove IRI from JSON during deserialization?

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core

I am working on a project that uses a 3rd party API that returns JSON-LD with IRI (Internationalized Resource Identifiers) in some of the values returned. I don't have any use for the relative paths that are returned and I only need the ID portion (see gender and marital status below). How can I strip that extra fluff off? Is there some reason it exists that I am missing? Any assistance and clarification is appreciated.

```
{
  "id": 123456,
  "firstName": "Homer",
  "middleName": "J",
  "lastName": "Simpson",
  "gender": "/resources/genders/1",
  "height": "",
  "weight": "",
  "maritalStatus": "/resources/marital_statuses/1"
}
```

Comment: By IRI, I'm assuming you're referring to [Internationalized Resource Identifiers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3987#section-2). I find it's good to have a definition of TLAs (three letter acronyms) when used :)

Comment: When deserializing, all fields without a matching property should just be ignored. So have you tried to deserialize to a class with only the properties you want?

Comment: you might string split the string on forward slash and return the last value of the array.

Comment: @JonasH I can't ignore these fields. The issue is when deserializing I want '/resources/genders/1' to just be '1'.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do that *during* deserialization, at least not unless you do some manual deserialization. You probably need to extract the IDs as a post-deserialization step.